# Best way to have resizable, vertical panes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, I should start by saying my knowledge of JQuery and CSS are not extensive, but I can handle basic code well and most moderate code.

I am currently trying to design a website layout that has vertical resizable panes.  Here is what I mean:

```
____________________________
|                 |         |
|                 |         |
|                 |         |
|                 |         |
|_________________|_________|
```

So I want the default to be about 75% width on the left, then 25% on the right, but you can drag the vertical bar to resize left and right.  Then each of these panels will run their own ajax.

So far I have tried using straight CSS, JQuery, and the library JSplitter only to find out that Jsplitter doesn't work on Chrome with jquery 1.8+.  Does anyone have any suggestions for simple ways to achieve what I want?  If you even link me to a tutorial or library you know, that would be great, but I have yet to find anything in the last 3 hours I have been struggling with this... Thanks for your help.

EDIT:  Oh and I have tried UI Layout, but the examples I looked at are really complicated... If someone has a simple example that would help too, I understand UI Layout is very powerful.

Comment: change your 75% width to 74%... IF that doesnt work add your css code and html.

Comment: Post the css to help make this question easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this sample as an initial approach: http://jsfiddle.net/amontellano/hM92y/1/

Click on the || mark in the middle and move it to expand left panel.

```
$('.rsh').draggable({
    axis: 'x', 
    containment: 'parent',
    helper: 'clone', 
    drag: function (event, ui) { 
        var width = ui.offset.left; 
        $(this).prev().width(width); 
    } 
});
```

It is using just div elements as containers.
Then, you should start playing and adding enhancements to this.
Hope it helps as an initial idea. You don't need any other library just jQuery UI.